# Doctrine DQL find by onetomany where last result does not match string

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine

I am currently struggling with a simple dql request. I have the following entities (simplified version):

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProductRepository::class)]
class Product extends AbstractProduct implements ExportInterface
{
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'product', targetEntity: ListingRequestValidationStatus::class, cascade: ['persist'], orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $listingRequestValidationStatuses;
}
```

And the relationship entity:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ListingRequestValidationStatusRepository::class)]
class ListingRequestValidationStatus
{
    const STATUS = ['SUBMITTED' => 'SUBMITTED', 'APPROVED' => 'APPROVED', 'REFUSED' => 'REFUSED'];

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $status = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $comment = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'listingRequestValidationStatuses')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Product $product = null;
}
```

In the DB, for the ListingRequestValidationStatus, I have the following:

[image]

And for my products:

---

[image]

---

All of my products are not referenced in the ListingRequestValidationStatus. Once a product is 'approved' its status cannot change.
I need to make a DQL query to retrieve all the products whose last status is not 'APPROVED' **AND** all the products not listed in the ListingRequestValidationStatus.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: not ChatGPT here, show your DQL please.

Comment: In you case, you should use sub query, example: `SELECT * FROM products p WHERE (SELECT status FROM validation_statuses vs WHERE vs.product_id = p.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) = 'APPROVED'`. In this query, you must get last element from related table and compare in root query.